# azure data factory - removing backslahes from a string - replace function does not work

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a web task passing data to an api in data factory.
The api only accepts a malformed json fragment:

```
[
    {
    "RowNumber":1,"Tag":"ddddd",
    "LastUpdateDateTime":"2022-07-26T13:14:28Z"
    }
]
```

Datafactory wont allow this to be converted to json with the json function as its not valid json.
But if its sent in the body as a string, all the double quotes are escaped:

```
[
{
\"RowNumber\":1,
\"Tag\":\"ddddd\",
\"LastModifiedDate\":\"2022-07-26T13:14:28Z\"
}
]
```

is there any way I can remove the backslashes in data factory without to do all this in an azure function?

Comment: It is a valid Json, did you try in Json setting : "Array of objects" that will parse it well.

Comment: can you please edit your question and provide more info about your pipeline?

Answer (score -1):

seems replace does remove the back slashes when sending the data between tasks, it just puts it in again if i try to view the output of the task!

using replace fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you add the code here , is it @replace('\', '') or @replace('\\','')

Comment: if you have a string with "\", then @replace('\', '') will do the job.